# How can I erase my hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have an old Alienware computer. I am upgrading to a new model. My Alienware is around 8 years old. My wife says I want your old one when you get the new one. That's fine, but there are sites and lots of things I don't want her to see.

How do I erase these things so she can't find a way to get to them. We were separated for a year and I dated until we got back together. All the dating stuff I know is still on there.

Comment: Just wipe the drive and put a new OS on it and that’s that.

Comment: What research have you done?  [Reset or reinstall Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reset-or-reinstall-windows-cd352bd8-4cb6-411a-f2f5-1814bd8d453c), what step of the process to Reset Windows, are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: If it is an SSD then simply reinstall windows with the remove all your data option is enough. Then simply make sure that the fresh OS runs TRIM by [optimising the disk](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/defragment-your-windows-10-pc-048aefac-7f1f-4632-d48a-9700c4ec702a). If it is an HDD then use [DBAN to wipe the disk](https://dban.org/)